# Passing event argument to the jquery bind function

Tags: jquery

When i am going through the existing code  found the below bind function

```
$('#tnav div[id$="linebox"].linebox').bind("click._ld",function(){
  alert('test');

        });
```

In the  bind function argument "click._ld"  what does _ld means here?  i used to find only "click" as argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`click._ld` means bind the click event handler given a *namespace*.

As from the jQuery docs:

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
>   removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple"
>   defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
>   click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
>   removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without
>   disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
>   are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
>   name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are
>   reserved for jQuery's use.

So you could trigger the click handler but just for that one namespace:

```
$(selector).trigger('click.yournamespace');
```

One example:

```
$(selector).bind('click.foo', function() {
    alert("foo!");
});

$(selector).bind('click', function() {
    alert("foobar!");
});

$(selector).trigger('click'); // alerts foo and foobar
$(selector).trigger('click.foo'); // alerts foo only
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  "Namespaces beginning with an underscore are reserved for jQuery's use."  why "_" was added to ld namespace.  what does it mean for jquery use.   If i remove it is it fine?   Also if i have two click events on a selector which one gets fired first?  Is there any rule in jquery?

Comment: i dont know that, I guess in the order they were binded. Just google that one